# What is Vanilla Bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I recently came across the term Vanilla Bootstrap while reading some posts.

I would just like to know what is Vanilla Bootstrap and is there any difference between this and Twitter-Bootstrap?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The term `Vanilla` is generally used to indicate that there are no additional features, plug ins or changes made to a library from it's default state. (see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vanilla_software)

In this case, it would indicate that the base Bootstrap library is in use without any additional extensions added onto it.

Comment: Hi Steve, thanks. So does that mean if I use regular twitter-bootstrap without any additional features that this would also be classified as Vanilla Bootstrap?

Comment: I would say so. Vanilla is just an adjective in this case to describe a basic installation.

Comment: So basically it is just an adjective applied to a basic installation.

Comment: Yes, the term comes from Vanilla icecream, just basic without any extras.